# Reverse grouped barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data for 35 participants like [image: where the first column is Ethnicity and the rest three columns are metabolites values]

,where the first column is Ethnicity and the rest three columns are values for three metabolites , I need to have a bar plot like [image: barplot of metabolites values]

for each metabolites grouped by Ethnicity. I tried different ways but they are not successful. I would appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will take the dummy data group by enzyme and ethicity to summarize and get a mean value of the column 'value' and then make the plot. In geom_col the position="dodge" can help make the "grouped" columns and coord_flip will flip the x and y axis.

```
 library(tidyverse)
    #dummy data
    data <- tibble(participant = 1:30,
                   ethnicity = sample(c("e1", "e2"), 30, replace = T),
                   value = sample(-10:10, 30, replace = T),
                   enzyme = c(rep("enzyme1", 10), rep("enzyme2", 10), rep("enzyme3", 10)))
    #get mean value of 'value'
    data2 <- data %>% 
      group_by(enzyme, ethnicity) %>% 
      summarize(value = mean(value))

    ggplot()+
      geom_col(data = data2, aes(x = enzyme, 
                                y = value, 
                                fill = ethnicity),
               position = "dodge")+
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))+
      coord_flip()+
      theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

Additionally, if you data has the values of the enzyme in 3 separate columns you should transform from the data to long format using pivot_longer to make the plotting easier:

```
data_wide <- tibble(ethnicity = c("ethnicity1", "ethnicity2"),
                    enzyme1 = c(-1, -2), 
                    enzyme2 = c(0, 0),
                    enzyme3 = c(1, 2))
    # A tibble: 2 x 4
  ethnicity   enzyme1 enzyme2 enzyme3
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 ethnicity1      -1       0       1
2 ethnicity2      -2       0       2


   #transform to long
data_long <- data_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("enzyme"), "enzyme")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ethnicity   enzyme  value
  <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
1 ethnicity1 enzyme1    -1
2 ethnicity1 enzyme2     0
3 ethnicity1 enzyme3     1
4 ethnicity2 enzyme1    -2
5 ethnicity2 enzyme2     0
6 ethnicity2 enzyme3     2
```

Comment: Thanks! But on the Y axis we should have the metabolites names like (A, B and C) and on the X axis we should have these metabolite values (those that are stated in the table).

Comment: Updated the answer so enzyme is on y-axis and value is on the x-axis. The enzymes are separated and grouped by ethnicity.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I made the figure separately foe ethnicity1 and ethnicity2 using the following commands. Do you know how to change the code to have different colors for decreasing and increasing values (eg. for more that zero and less that zero)? Thanks.                                           data_long1=subset(data_long, ethnicity=="ethnicity1")
ggplot()+
  geom_col(data = data_long1, aes(x = enzyme, 
                             y = value),
           position = "dodge")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_linedraw()

Comment: This is the answer to my second question:                                                                                                             data_long1[["sign"]] = ifelse(data_long1[["value"]] >= 0, "positive", "negative")


ggplot()+
  geom_col(data = data_long1, aes(x = enzyme, 
                             y = value,fill = sign))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_linedraw()+ geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive" = "green", "negative" = "red"))